# Fetch data including CKReference from CloudKit

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecordzone

I have been using CloudKit service for a long time, and thus storing a lot of data in there. Now, I have a second device connecting to CloudKit, and thus fetching all the data.

Say I have two record types **Task** and **List**, where **Task** has a CKReference pointing to **List**. Typically, when each record is processed, I will persist that to local cache. The actual scenario is more complicated with multiple relationships.

**Question:**

What happened if a **Task** record arrives, but its linked **List** record is not here yet?

Should I cache this record for later processing, or initiate a separate per record operation to pull that particular **List** first?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here in [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/AddingReferences/AddingReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH7-SW2).

Basically the suggestion is to fetch the missing records specifically (e.g. using **CKFetchRecordsOperation**), and then apply the updates to local cache.